# Checking for number-type definitions in SQL system

Tags: sql-server, types, casting, precision

I have a SQL Server database with heavy logic/data-processing components.
Lots of raw tables, "working tables", sprocs, functions, views. The works.

I've been tasked with converting a particular conceptual value that is heavily passed around from being handled mostly as an int(but occasionally at 2 d.p.), to being handled to 3 d.p.
Yeuch!

Naming isn't too bad, so you can generally tell if a column/variable/parameter is holding this type of data just from it's name.

So far I have checked:

- Table columns (`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`)
- Sproc and Func Params (In & Out) (`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS`)
- Search all sprocs/funcs/views for instances of `DECLARE`, `CAST` and `CONVERT`
- Attempting to locate any known places that perform any divisions to ensure that they aren't doing integer division.

Does anyone have any suggestions for places that I might have missed that might be silently storing one of these values as an int (or as the wrong precision)?

Comment: what is `2 dp` and `3 dp`

Comment: "decimal places"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find it in SP/view/ufn definitions, this may help (literally searches in definitions so can be used to find any kind of strings):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      o.name AS Object_Name
    , o.type_desc
FROM
    sys.sql_modules m
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o
        ON m.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE
    m.definition Like '%$ObjectName$%'
```

Otherwise you can find the referencing, depending object using these (works with objects only, so no column names, but you can always join sys.columns too)

```
SELECT
      referencing_schema_name
    , referencing_entity_name
    , referencing_id
    , referencing_class_desc
    , is_caller_dependent
FROM
    sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('$ObjectName$', 'OBJECT')
;

SELECT
      referenced_id
    , referenced_entity_name AS table_name
    , referenced_minor_name as column_name
    , is_all_columns_found
FROM
    sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities ('$ObjectName$', 'OBJECT')
;

SELECT
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME ( referencing_id ) AS referencing_schema_name,  
    OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id) AS referencing_entity_name,   
    o.type_desc AS referencing_desciption,   
    COALESCE(COL_NAME(referencing_id, referencing_minor_id), '(n/a)') AS referencing_minor_id,   
    referencing_class_desc, referenced_class_desc,  
    referenced_server_name, referenced_database_name, referenced_schema_name,  
    referenced_entity_name,   
    COALESCE(COL_NAME(referenced_id, referenced_minor_id), '(n/a)') AS referenced_column_name,  
    is_caller_dependent, is_ambiguous  
FROM
    sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS sed  
    INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
        ON sed.referencing_id = o.object_id  
WHERE
    referenced_id = OBJECT_ID(N'$ObjectName$')
;
```

Comment: The first block is exactly how I've been doing the searches currently. Second block seems interesting, though I'm not entirely clear what it's doing yet - I'll take a look :)

Comment: Then nothing new to you, sorry. The wonders of edit. You have something to play with, have fun :)